# How to find current SQL statment that causes Deadlock in oracle?

Tags: oracle, deadlock

how can i find the exact current SQL statment that are causing other sessions deadlock in oracle ?

Comment: Both statements will be listed in the trace file that Oracle generates when one of the sessions is killed once Oracle detects the deadlock

Answer (score 0):

Look for blocking instance and blocking session in v$session.

```
select * from v$session
```

That should let you know the SID and SERIAL# of the blocking session.

Edit -- This is for a blocked session, not a deadlock.
If it is an actual deadlock it should automatically clear ( eventually ).
BTW According to AskTom 'The #1 cause of deadlocks in Oracle is due to unindexed foriegn keys.'

```
select vs.blocking_session from v$session vs
where vs.sid in
(
select userenv('sid') as sid from dual
);
```

If this is not NULL then use the SID for this
select * from v$session vs
where vs.SID = 'BLOCKING SESSION FROM ABOVE' ;

Comment: When you have a deadlock then the session is **not** blocked - Oracle cancels the statements which caused the deadlock.

Comment: Can you give me full SQL Statment to show the current SQL that are causing the deadlock